# Counting working days in a month

Tags: postgresql, count, date, range-types

I wrote this query that suppose to count the working days in a month but I get the following error:

> *[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision + interval Hinweis: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 305*

The date is a timestamp and this is the function below serves as the denominator to normalize sales:

```
(count(((date_part('month',date))+ Interval '1 month'- Interval '1 day')-(date_part('month',date)))
           filter (where date_part('dow', date) not in (6,0)))
```

In the end I will have:

```
select date_part('month', date) as month, 
sum(sales)/denominator as Monthly_noralized_sales
from sales;
```

Comment: I have no idea what `(date_part('month',date) + Interval '1 month'- Interval '1 day') - (date_part('month',date))` is supposed to do. Additionally it seems pointless to pass that expression to the `count()` aggregate as it is essentially the same as `count(date)` - i.e. it will include all rows where `date is not null`. Which is also achieved by your `filter` anyway as that will also exclude rows where `date` is null. So it seems you can simplify that to `count(*) filter (where date_part(..) not in (..))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you're trying to achieve, but to count working days you need a range of dates.

IMHO the best way to deal with dates is by using a calendar table. Keep in mine that you need to add holidays and days off to your calendar. You can find a lot of samples googling a bit.

If you don't have/want to use a calendar table, you can take advantage of [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function.

```
create table t (dt timestamp);
insert into t values ('20200110'),('20200203'),('20200715');

select 
    date_part('month', dts) mt,
    count(*) as wd
from
    (select
        generate_series(date_trunc('month', dt)::date,
                        (date_trunc('month', dt)::date 
                                    + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date,
                        interval '1 day') dts
     from 
        t) t2
where
    date_part('dow', dts) <> 6
group by
    date_part('month', dts);
```

> ```
> mt | wd
> :- | -:
> 7  | 27
> 1  | 27
> 2  | 24
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b71aa1f14344fa4c572c608ef97e1239)*